# Start node app when running docker container from cli

Tags: node.js, docker, packer

I'm relatively new to `Docker` and have a `node` web server which I have added to a `docker image`. My image is built using `packer`, so I don't have a `Dockerfile`.

My question is when running the `docker container` on the command line with `docker run -it -d <imageId>` is there a way to pass in the command to run my web server that resides in the container?
So something like `docker run -it -d <imageId> npm start`

Comment: Did you try what you suggested? ´docker run -it -d <imageId> npm start´ it should actually work. Except npm ist not in PATH, then you can try give the absolute path `/usr/local/bin/npm` or whatever it is.

Comment: I did, but the container is exited as soon as it's run. I've also tried what is suggested in the docs (they use nginx as an example) `$ docker run -d -p 80:80 my_image nginx -g 'daemon off;'` and still, when I check to see if the container is running, it has exited already.

Comment: Is `npm start` the command that actually starts the service (and keeps running) or does it start a service using init/upstart/systemd/whatever and then quit?

Comment: it starts the service and keeps running I guess. It looks at the package.json file and runs `node server.js`
Even if I change `npm start` to `node server.js` the same thing still happens.

Comment: I've just noticed that if I run my image without the command to run the webserver and then in the container shell run the server it returns an error. Perhaps this is causing the run command to fail

Comment: That sounds likely if you run the command without the -d you should be able to see the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working with

`docker run -it -d -w /path/to/code/folder <imageName:version> node server.js 'daemon off;'`